# Symfony2 many to one get null parameter

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a many-to-one relationship with the 'login_log' and 'user_info' and 'user_account'. this is three entity's summary.

```
class UserInfo extends Entity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $userId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="true_name", type="string", length=20)
     */
    protected $trueName;

    ...
}



class UserAccount extends Entity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $userId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $userName;

    ...
}




class LoginLog extends Entity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="log_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $logId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserInfo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    protected $userInfo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserAccount")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    protected $userAccount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $userId;

    ...
}
```

when i want add login log:

```
$log = new LoginLog();
$log->setUserId(11);
$em->persist($log);
$em->flush();
```

but in symfony profiler, i got those query:

```
INSERT INTO login_log (user_id) VALUES(?) 
Parameters: { 1: null}
```

why first parameters is null!

Comment: when i remove many-to-one relationship, it work ok!

Comment: Because that is supposed to be an association. Use the ID you have to find the related record with it, that being `UserInfo` and use the result instead of the hard-coded ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this makes no sence :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserAccount")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    protected $userAccount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $userId;
```

they are both using the same columnname,    get rid of the userId property, and use a setter for userAccount.

Right now,   you are setting one thing, and when makeing the query, doctrine freaks out, and uses the other one.

Understand what i mean ?

```
$log = new LoginLog();
$log->setUserAccount($user);  // $user beeing an actual user, not an ID
$em->persist($log);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks.In some cases, I got a trusted UserID value, and I do not need to query UserAccount data. So, then I slightly modified framework code.